# ApexTrack: peak tail looks like a shoulder

Tags: software, chromatography

I'm trying to implement ApexTrack algorithm in my software by following the description written by Waters. But many chromatograms that I see have noticeable tailing of peaks: [image: fronting of peaks].

No matter what Touchdown% threshold I set (even 0) - it won't be able to go past the bump in the tail because the slope becomes positive for a bit.

Are there modifications to ApexTrack that could join such tail to the peak? And at the same time keep recognizing true shoulders (which you see to the left of the largest peak).

Comment: Stanislav, the terminology you are using is not correct. The arrow shows peak tailing. Front side is the early eluting side. This would help in communication with analytical chemists. I think you can significantly get rid of this tailing by simply modifying your chromatography methods. This will always cause trouble in experimentation regardless of any software. Could you mention if this is a single component chromatogram or two components which are co-eluting? Secondly have you used PeakFit?

Comment: Oops. Corrected the wording, thanks! The tail and the peak seem to be the same compound. No, I haven't tried PeakFit, should I? :)

Comment: Yes, please. It will make your life much easier! PeakFit can easily fit exponentially modified Gaussians after smoothing. You did not mention, if you have a single compound or a two compounds? If it were a single compound, and you see a shoulder, this is an indication of a clogged or damaged column.